# Where is located asp.net identity controller and its views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I created .net core website application with individual user accounts settings

[image]

I can manage my account in website navigation

[image]

But i wonder, where are these files (controller and views) located in the project ?

[image]

I thought it should be in the Identity Area but the folder is empty, what am I missing ?

Comment: Right click on Identity/Pages node, select Add => Scaffolded Item. Next Select the Identity node and continue. You will see all the pages and you can add them explicitly to your project if you want to change them

Comment: Here the long story https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Of course we already have a duplicate